# Split parent node into two siblings at given node

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a XML (example below) and I need to split one node into two at a certain child node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx>
  <trk>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt>
        <time>2014-01-16T14:33:35.000Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt>
        <time>2014-01-16T14:33:39.000Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt>
        <time>2014-01-16T15:44:14.000Z</time>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

This is the resulting XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx>
  <trk>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt>
        <time>2014-01-16T14:33:35.000Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt>
        <time>2014-01-16T14:33:39.000Z</time>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>   <-- this line is new
    <trkseg>    <-- this line is new
      <trkpt>
        <time>2014-01-16T15:44:14.000Z</time>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

This XML is somewhat fixed, in reality there is thousands of trkpt's.

I have no problem finding where to do the split using Nokogiri but I have no good idea how to make the split.

Comment: I didn't get you, what exactly you are looking for. I can see 4 comment nodes you have added.

Comment: Your question is very interesting, but need more information to solve it.

Comment: The comment nodes are not really nodes, just comments.. What I wish for is to have two trkseg's. The first with two trkpt's and the second with one trkpt.

Comment: I didn't understand the line *The first with two trkpt's and the second with one trkpt.*..

Comment: I've tried to explain it more in the question

Comment: I also tried to help you out.. Please check this out and let me know if any confusions you are having...

Answer (score 1):

You may find this easier if you think in terms of nodes of the parsed data structure rather than textual XML elements.

In this case you want to add a new `trkseg` node after the first, then remove the last `trkpt` node and move it to this new node. Something like this should work:

```ruby
d = Nokogiri.XML(the_original_xml)

# find the node to move and remove it from its current position
trkpt3 = d.at_xpath("//trkpt[3]")
trkpt3.remove

# create a new node of type trkseg
new_node = d.create_element("trkseg")

# add the trkpt3 node to this new node
new_node.add_child(trkpt3)

# add the new node into position as a child of the trk node
d.at_xpath("//trk").add_child(new_node)
```

The actual result of this isn’t quite the same as what you’re after, as it doesn’t account for the whitespace nodes, but otherwise the structure is the same – it looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx>
  <trk>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt>
        <time>2014-01-16T14:33:35.000Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt>
        <time>2014-01-16T14:33:39.000Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      
    </trkseg>
  <trkseg><trkpt>
        <time>2014-01-16T15:44:14.000Z</time>
      </trkpt></trkseg></trk>
</gpx>
```

If it was important you could be more precise with how you reconstruct the document to get exactly the result you need.

You’ll probably need different XPath queries than this in a real situation, but the general idea of manipulating the DOM structure with methods like [`remove`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-remove), [`add_child`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-add_child), [`<<`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-3C-3C), [`create_element`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-create_element), and [`create_text_node`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-create_text_node) is what you need.

---

#### A general purpose method

Here’s an example of a method you can use to split a node into, with the split being after the node passed in as an argument:

```ruby
def split_after(node)
  # Find all the nodes to be moved to the new node
  to_move = node.xpath("following-sibling::node()")
  # The parent node, this is the node that will be "split"
  p = node.parent

  # Create the new node
  new_node = node.document.create_element(p.name)

  # Remove the nodes from the original position
  # and add them to the new node
  to_move.remove
  new_node << to_move

  # Insert the new node into the correct position
  p.add_next_sibling(new_node)
end
```

This uses [`add_next_sibling`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-add_next_sibling), which ensures the new node is added in the correct position when the node being split itself has siblings.

Comment: Thank you. In reality there are thousands of nodes, not just those three. I added that the question.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand the approach will be the same whatever – select the nodes to move, remove them, create the new node in place, add the moved nodes to the new node. You can remove and add entire nodesets at once, you don’t have to do it one at a time.

Comment: +1 "You can remove and add entire nodesets at once, you don’t have to do it one at a time." That's the beauty of working with a DOM. Once the content is parsed, we can prune entire branches and move them wherever we want, and they'll be intact. And, because XML *should* be symmetrical we can iterate over it doing the same action repeatedly.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand I’ve added an example of a method that can split a node in the general case, it might help explain what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I would do as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc_string = <<-xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx>
  <trk>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt>
        <time>2014-01-16T14:33:35.000Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt>
        <time>2014-01-16T14:33:39.000Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt>
        <time>2014-01-16T15:44:14.000Z</time>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
xml

doc = Nokogiri.XML(doc_string) do |config|
  config.default_xml.noblanks
end

# First I find the node, onto which I would split as an example.
split_node = doc.at("//trkpt[last()]")

# I took out the parent node of the node onto which I will split later.
parent_node_of_split_node = split_node.parent

# Now I am removing the splitting node from the main xml document.
split_node.unlink

# Now I am creating a new node of type <trkseg>, into which I will add splitting node
# as a child node.
new_node_to_add = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('trkseg',doc)

# added the splitting node as a child node to the newly created node <trkseg>
new_node_to_add.add_child split_node

# below line I hope clear by seeing to the local variables names as I have written
new_node_to_add.parent = parent_node_of_split_node.parent

puts doc.to_xml(:indent => 2)

# >> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
# >> <gpx>
# >>   <trk>
# >>     <trkseg>
# >>       <trkpt>
# >>         <time>2014-01-16T14:33:35.000Z</time>
# >>       </trkpt>
# >>       <trkpt>
# >>         <time>2014-01-16T14:33:39.000Z</time>
# >>       </trkpt>
# >>     </trkseg>
# >>     <trkseg>
# >>       <trkpt>
# >>         <time>2014-01-16T15:44:14.000Z</time>
# >>       </trkpt>
# >>     </trkseg>
# >>   </trk>
# >> </gpx>
```

Methods that I have used here :

- [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at)
- [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#to_xml`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-to_xml)
- [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#parent`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-parent)
- [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#unlink`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-unlink)
- [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#add_child`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-add_child)
- [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#parent=`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-parent-3D)

Comment: Thank you. In reality there are thousands of nodes, not just those three. I added that the question.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand This is how you can approach to the solution, now actual you know better than us, think about it and code it and apply the solution here we have provided, wherever it does fit well. But this way you can go.. I am sure.